# using jq delete key value pair when value contains a specific string

Tags: json, shell, command-line-interface, key-value, jq

Using jq I need to delete a specific key:value pair if value contains string "null". The string could be " null" or "null ". Hence need to use contains and not exact string match. If not a string it will be a number

My sample json is as below: (The null value is expected only in the 'th' and 'sf' keys)

```
'dets':{
   'S1':{
        'type':'class',
        'input': [12,7,6,19],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile1',
                 'th': -10,
                 'sf': 'null'
                }
         },
    'S2':{
        'type':'class',
        'input': [12,7,6,19],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile2',
                 'th': -5,
                 'sf': 3
                }
         },
    'S3':{
        'type':'bottom',
        'input': [12,7,16],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile3',
                 'th': ' null',
                 'sf': 'null '
                }
         }
    }
```

The required output should be like:

```
    'dets':{
   'S1':{
        'type':'class',
        'input': [12,7,6,19],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile1',
                 'th': -10
                }
         },
    'S2':{
        'type':'class',
        'input': [12,7,6,19],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile2',
                 'th': -5,
                 'sf': 3
                }
         },
    'S3':{
        'type':'bottom',
        'input': [12,7,16],
        'config':{
                'file':'sfile3'
                }
         }
    }
```

I believe something on the lines of del(.[][].config.smoothing_span | select(contains("null"))) but i am running into a problem since type is different.

Answer (score 3):

1. The given data is not valid JSON but it is valid [HJSON](http://hjson.org/), so the first step in the following jq-oriented solution is to use hjson to convert the data to JSON:

   `hjson -j input.hjson`
2. The concept of what values should be regarded as "null" might change over time, so in the following let's define a filter that can be used to capture whichever definition is appropriate, e.g.

   `def isnull: . == null or (type=="string" and test("null"));`

(Perhaps a better definition would use `test("^ *null *$")`.)

3. If you want to delete all keys whose value `isnull`, you could use `walk/1`:

`walk(if type=="object"
         then with_entries(select(.value|isnull|not))
         else . end)`

(If your jq does not have walk, you could simply copy-and-paste its definition from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq or elsewhere on the web.)

Assuming your jq has `walk`, we could therefore write:

```
hjson -j input.hjson |
  jq 'def isnull: . == null or (type=="string" and test("null")); 
      walk(if type=="object" 
           then with_entries(select(.value|isnull|not))
           else . end)'
```

4. If you want to "walk" the input but restrict attention to specific keys, you can easily modify the selection criterion in (3).

#### delkey

If you want the scope of the changes to be as narrow as possible, you could use `map_values`, e.g. in conjunction with a helper function for checking and possibly deleting a specific key:

```
  # key is assumed to be a filter, e.g. .foo
  def delkey(key): if key | isnull then del(key) else . end;
  .dets |= map_values(.config |= (delkey(.th) | delkey(.sf)))
```

#### delkeys

If there are several specific keys to be checked, it might be more convenient to define a function for checking a list of keys:

```
# keys is assumed to be an array of strings
def delkeys(keys):
  with_entries(select(.key as $k
    | (keys|index($k)) and (.value|isnull) | not));

.dets |= map_values(.config |= delkeys(["th", "sf"]))
```